# Laravel: Output from database

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I must be missing something, since my code isn't working, but I have tried to figure it out for a while now without any luck.

I am trying to output a single column content from a table, which represents all the text-bits throughout a simple website, which I want to be able to edit and update in the table, with a simple cms, which I have created.

[These are my controllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TuYG.png)

[And my Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpZR7.png)

I would like to do this in my index.blade.php
{{ $indexHeading }}

I get the error message: undefined variable: texts, I must be missing a link between something.

I am a beginner, and I'm hoping I just made a simple mistake, which I am not skilled enough to see :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post blade file and full error message?

Comment: That makes sense, how would you do that? :)
 return view('index',  ['texts' => $texts]);
It is in that line, right?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and post your code? It's difficult with images!

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought it might be easier to see the different files

Comment: @Rahi I can't post any more photos
in MainController.php line 17
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined variable: texts', 'E:\\projects\\prettyfitlv\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\MainController.php', 17, array('indexHeading' => 'SomethingSomethingSomething')) in MainController.php line 17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `MainController` you are passing `texts` without creating it.

Comment: But is it the right way to pass texts?
Do I create it by saying $texts = Text::find....?

Comment: try rename `$texts` with `$indexHeading` or pass `$indexHeading` instead of `$texts`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass data from your controller to view

```
View('index',['texts'=>$yourvalue);
```

Then you can access text variable in the view file.